# pd.to_numeric not working

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am facing a weird problem with pandas.

I donot know where I am going wrong?

[image]

But when I am creating a new df, there seems to be no problem. like

[image]

Any idea why?

Edit :

```
sat=pd.read_csv("2012_SAT_Results.csv")
sat.head()
#converted columns to numeric types
sat.iloc[:,2:]=sat.iloc[:,2:].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors="coerce")
sat.dtypes
sat_1=sat.iloc[:,2:].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors="coerce")
sat_1.head()
```

Comment: Can't tell, provide complete code to demo the problem.

Comment: With your reputation score I expect you to know that code, error messages, and data should be posted as text, never as pictures.

Comment: This is a [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20635) but I don't know if there is a workaround. I iterated over columns and converted to number when I faced it.

Comment: @Mr.T ,I built my reputation in MSE,Had there been an error, I would have written the code, but i thought that giving a pic would help understand the problem better.

Comment: You should always post text so users can copy/paste it into their IDE and search engines can index/find the problem better.

Comment: @Mr.T,thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you can't apply `to_numeric` directly using `.iloc` appears to be a bug, but to get the same results that you're looking for (applying `to_numeric` to multiple columns at the same time), you could instead use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['1','2'],'b':['3','4']})

# If you're applying to entire columns
df[df.columns[1:]] = df[df.columns[1:]].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors = 'coerce')

# If you want to apply to specific rows within columns
df.loc[df.index[1:], df.columns[1:]] = df.loc[df.index[1:], df.columns[1:]].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors = 'coerce')
```

Comment: Thank you @elPastor, very weird error but you saved the day !

Comment: I have a similar problem, but this didn't fix the issue. The cell values are still strings after applying to_numeric to those columns.